# VBA FileFormat to save as .xls

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro to save the active worksheet to a new workbook. However it wants to save it as .xlsx and I need it to save as .xls

```
Private Sub SaveBarList_Click()
ActiveSheet.Copy
With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    .Copy
    .PasteSpecial xlValues
    .PasteSpecial xlFormats
End With
Dim strDir As String

'Show standard save as dialogue box
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
    If .Show = -1 Then
        strDir = .SelectedItems(1)
    End If
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Application.GetSaveAsFilename, FileFormat:=-4143
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd suggest using the enum `xlWorkbookNormal` instead of the value (-4143), simply for readability. That said, you do have the right number. Have you tried removing the extra `x` from the file name, then opening the file in Excel?  I'd guess that your FileDialog is returning a name complete with the `.xlsx` extension & Excel is just saving it under the name it's told to, even though the format is correct. If you can open it with the `.xls` extension, change the extension before saving.

Comment: For the fileformat, try [57](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac020.htm). and edit the save line to `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\YourUserName\Desktop\FILENAME.xlsm", fileformat:=57`

Comment: @user3578951, I'd assume that the xls**m** is a typo? Also, `57` looks to be a Mac specific number (there is no Win Excel2011), and the OP doesn't specify, so you may be correct. The Win version of `57` is `56` which would be `xlExcel8`, and that may work, too.

Comment: I am using excel 2013. Trying to fool proof the form to save as .xls for anyone that uses it. We have a program to import the information back into but it only accepts .xls, I know I can change it at the save as dialog box but not everyone will do that.

Comment: How about just using a line similar to `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\User\Blah\SaveFolder\theFileName.xls", FileFormat:=56`

Comment: Because the user and file name changes. I have tried adding the `FileFormat:=56` but that has not changed anything.

Comment: Have you tried the rename I suggested in my initial comment? If that works, you can still ask the user for the file name, but then, in your code, check the last 5 chars for `.xlsx` and if they are, just trim of the `x`.

Comment: I found a solution online using this code. It seems to work.
`Private Sub SaveBarList_Click()
   ActiveSheet.Copy
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        .Copy
        .PasteSpecial xlValues
        .PasteSpecial xlFormats
    End With
    Dim fname
        fname = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.XLS), *.XLS", Title:="Save As")
        If fname = False Then Exit Sub
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=fname


    ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub`

Comment: Why don't you post your code as an answer. You're allowed to do so (though you may have to wait until tomorrow). It's more readable, and, once you accept your answer, it's easier for others to find and make use of.

Answer (score 3):

The [ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841185.aspx) has a member that allows different file formats: [XlFileFormat Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff198017.aspx). There are several formats available through this beside .xlsx, including .xls.

Please note that MSDN's article on .SaveAs (first link above) says "For an existing file, the default format is the last file format specified; for a new file, the default is the format of the version of Excel being used."