# File exported from Microsoft Access save as .XLSM

Tags: ms-access, xlsx, save-as

I run data through Access, and it spits out an Excel 95 file, which I run a macro to format the data into readable columns. It saves automatically to a desktop folder, but I want it to save as a .xlsx. It's my understanding that Access cannot do this, so I created code to save an additional copy as a .xlsx and close the '95 file. However, the open .xlsx file is blank until I close out and re-open it. Is there a way to get it to load properly after the macro is run?

```
[...Bunch of code]

Dim PathA As String
Dim PathT As String
Dim fName As String

PathA = ActiveWorkbook.Path
PathT = ThisWorkbook.Path
fName = ActiveWorkbook.Name

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs PathA & "\" & fName & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

[image]

Comment: I am confused. You say Access cannot save as .xlsx yet you have code doing that. Did you mean to say "cannot save as .xls"? Why do you say that? I have code doing just that. Review https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29753833/vba-fileformat-to-save-as-xls. Why does title say "save as .xlsm"? How does Access "spit out" Excel95 file?